# Dissecting a figure into 2, 3, 4, and 5 parts but not 6

Tags: mathematics, geometry, dissection

This figure is divided in 2, 3 and 4 equal parts of same size and shape, but it is not possible to do it in 5 equal parts of same size and shape.

[image: In 2]
[image: In 3]
[image: In 4]

Is it possible to find a figure that can be divided in 2, 3, 4 and 5 equal parts of same size and shape but not in 6?

Comment: How can it be proven that a shape cannot be divided into some number of parts?

Comment: If the shape of the pieces created by slicing something into 3 is symmetrical, you can always have 6 slices (cut each one along that line of symmetry).

Comment: https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-a6d27cf641962cd22f60c30c589aa67d

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins yes, so if there is a solution the figure divided in 3 parts should not be symmetric

Comment: @Rodolfo and that’s as far as I got lol

Comment: You haven't defined what a "part" means. For example, can it be a nonmesurable set? Even if you have a definition of "part", you still need to give a proof that it cannot be divided into five parts.

Comment: It's Kurchan himself! Welcome. http://www.recmath.org/contest/Kurchan/description.php

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky wow, thank you! You can see in my web page https://www.puzzlefun.online/  all Puzzle Fun and Chess Puzzle Fun magazine with hundreds of problems

Comment: I have a feeling the answer is no but i have no idea how to proof it

Comment: @IvoBeckers: I have a feeling the answer is yes but I cannot find a solution. Can anyone find any set at all (measurable or not) that can be divided into 2,3,4 but not 6?

Comment: @user21820 or what about 2 and 3 only but not 6. I can't even come up with an example of that.

Comment: @IvoBeckers: Unfortunately, I wasn't even able to find an example of that, but it feels like people might already have. But if 2∧3∧4∧¬6 is impossible, then I think the reason is precisely that 2∧3∧¬6 is impossible.

Comment: @user21820 I think this shape might be one https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCcer.png as you can see it even has 3 different ways to divide in 3

Comment: @IvoBeckers: No that doesn't work at all; it can be divided into 6 identical pieces. =)

Comment: Proving that a shape cannot be dissected into a given number of parts [seems hard](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4362070/453192).

Comment: Like Ivo I think we should first consider whether 2 and 3 but not 6 parts is possible.  Somehow related there is a shape that can be cut in 2, 4, 6 but not 3 ; https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101289/sharing-a-field-among-4-sons

Comment: I just saw the case 2, 3 but not 6 has been answered: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4344411/can-a-figure-be-divided-into-2-and-3-but-not-6-equal-parts